# Set value for each instance of mesh in geometry nodes

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes, instances

In the Blender Geometry nodes editor, I am trying to populate a face with instances, and creating the instance mesh in a NodeGroup. I want to customize the height (length in a Curve Line) of each individual instance, with a different random height for each one. However, it seems to be that the NodeGroup is considered a single object. How can I make each instance different with a different height? I've attached some screenshots below. Thanks for any help!

[image: Input to instances]

[image: Inside the instance object]

Comment: short answer: you can't. You have to change these kind of things after the instancing. This question was asked a lot of times here, so maybe you wanna search here?